# pyaudio: unable to open slave [ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave]

Tags: python, pyaudio, zero, pi, portaudio

I had an [xkcd979](https://xkcd.com/979/) moment - [this post](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1192225) is the exact same problem I had, but it has no replies!

So, here it is:

I'm working with pyaudio on a clean, new Pi Zero 2, and it's erroring with the following:

```
Python 3.9.2 (default, Mar 12 2021, 04:06:34)
[GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyaudio
>>> stream = pyaudio.PyAudio()
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2660:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1075:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
```

The unknown PCM errors are fixable and I can do those - but it's that unable to open slave error that's holding the code and failing to properly start pyaudio.

So far, I've gone through about 30 different posts and solutions, but none have worked. I've set the card and device as default, I've tried a different USB adapter, I'm just yet to try a different USB audio dongle but pyaudio works absolutely fine on a Pi 3.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!
-Dan